# Does every infinite set $\Omega$ have a chain of subsets of length $2^{|\Omega|}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, order-theory

This question is motivated by the well-known fact that a countable set $\Omega$ has a chain of $2^{\aleph_0}$ many subsets. This, initially quite surprising, fact actually has a very simple proof:

Without loss of generality assume that $\Omega$ is the set of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$. For every real number $r$, let $A_r$ be the set of rationals strictly less than $r$. Then the set $\{A_r: r\in \mathbb{R}\}$ is a chain of length $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Now my question is, what if $\Omega$ is uncountable? Does the subset lattice of $\Omega$ always contain a chain of subsets of length $2^{|\Omega|}$? If not, what is the maximal length of a chain of subsets?

Comment: Can't you generalize the idea for $\aleph_0$ by an ascending Löwenheim-Skolem-thing ? Like, take any $\Omega$ you want, then pick an ordered set of cardinality $|\Omega|$ that's elementarily equivalent (as ordered sets) to $\mathbb{Q}$ . Then its completion (for instance Dedekind-McNeille completion) would be of cardinality $2^{|\Omega|}$ (maybe ?), which would prove the desired result. I'm not sure about it, the problem being : can any infinite linearly ordered dense set with no endpoints be densely embedded in another ordered set with the same properties and that has cardinality $2^\Omega$ ?

Comment: @Max I don't know. But a quick look at Wikipedia told me that the Loewenheim-Skolem theorem and Dedekind_McNeille completions are something I want to learn more about, so thanks Max!

Comment: @Max I sort of doubt a subset of same cardinal and elementarily equivalent to the rationals would be enough. Indeed, we have one choice: start from the given cardinal $\alpha$ and make the lexicographic product with the rationals. Then the completion will be the lexicographic product of $\alpha$ with the reals (with $-\infty$), a sort of long line. Its cardinal will only be $\max(\alpha,2^{\aleph_0})$. So a dense ordering (which, without min and max, is the same as being elementary equivalent to the rationals) of the same cardinal is not enough.

Comment: @YCor : I see your point. And indeed when I posted my comment I realized that the "maybe" I had written was there for a reason.

Comment: I feel this was asked before.

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/122031/totally-ordered-chain-in-the-powerset-with-big-cardinality

Comment: Yes, that's the same. Sorry about that and thanks for the link.